# os.path.basename(file) vs file.split("/")[-1]

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

I need to extract `seq_00034` from  a file path like

```
    file = "/home/user/workspace/data/seq_00034.pkl"
```

I know 2 ways to achieve it:

#### method.A

```
    import os
    seq_name = os.path.basename(file).split(".")[0]
```

or

#### method.B

```
    seq_name = file.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
```

Which is safer/faster?

(taking the cost of `import os` into account)

Is there a more elegent way to extract `seq_name` from given path?

Comment: "faster" --- are you doing millions of those operations a second?

Comment: No, not that amount of those operations. But I intend to find the "one" way to do it, following the Zen of Python

Comment: "Zen of Python" is not about performance and speed.

Comment: You are right. I don't know how to compare the two methods above if speed does not matter. Ps. The  `pathlib.Path.stem()` way is more understandable though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the more elegant way would be by using the [pathlib.Path.stem()](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) method

```py
import pathlib

filename =  "/home/user/workspace/data/seq_00034.pkl"
path = pathlib.Path(filename)

print(path.stem)
```

Answer (score 1):

speed test:

```
import os
import pathlib
import time

given_path = "/home/home/user/workspace/data/task_2022_02_xx_xx_xx_xx.pkl"

time1 = time.time()
for _ in range(10000):
    seq_name = given_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
print(time.time()-time1, 'time of split')


time2 = time.time()
for _ in range(10000):
    seq_name = pathlib.Path(given_path).stem
print(time.time()-time2, 'time of pathlib')


time3 = time.time()
for _ in range(10000):
    seq_name = os.path.basename(given_path).split(".")[0]
print(time.time()-time3, 'time of os.path')
```

result (on my PC) is:

```
0.00339508056640625 time of split
0.0355381965637207 time of pathlib
0.005405426025390625 time of os.path
```

It turns out `split twice` is faster than `os.path + split`, they both are significantly faster than using `pathlib`

---

if we take the time consumed for importing into account:

(assume the code is only called once)

```
time1 = time.time()
seq_name = given_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
print(time.time()-time1, 'time of split')

time2 = time.time()
import pathlib
seq_name = pathlib.Path(given_path).stem
print(time.time()-time2, 'time of pathlib')

time3 = time.time()
import os
seq_name = os.path.basename(given_path).split(".")[0]
print(time.time()-time3, 'time of os.path')
```

the result:

```
1.430511474609375e-06 time of split
0.003416776657104492 time of pathlib
3.0994415283203125e-06 time of os.path
```